# ui-router state to run a function and redirect in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I would like to create a menu item for the user to log out.
Basically what I need to do is to delete the cookie and redirect him to the login page.

I use ui-router, the login page is not a state of the app. It's actually in a different Angular app I use for authentication (don't ask...) so I'll have to $window.location.href him.

I thought about doing the following

```
  angular.module('logOut', [])
      .config(routeConfig);

  /** @ngInject */
  function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('logOut', {
          url: '/logOut',
          title: 'Log Out',
          controller: 'logOut',
          sidebarMeta: {
            icon: 'ion-help-buoy',
            order: 300
          }
        });
  }
```

And to create a logOut controller which will delete the cookie and redirect.

Is that the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can avoid logout state (or you'll first redirect to logout state of your app and then to another app), just remove cookies and redirect from your menu controller directly.